# Flex chart <backgroundelements>

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I can assign my charts backgroundelements property with a custom class I developed called RangeSelector in mxml like so:

```
            <mx:LineChart id="chart" width="100%" dataProvider="{dataSet}"  height="100%" mouseMove="updateDetails(event)">
                <mx:series>
                    <mx:LineSeries xField="h" yField="v" itemRenderer="mx.charts.renderers.CircleItemRenderer" radius="1.5"/>
                </mx:series>
                <mx:backgroundElements>
                    <qsc:RangeSelector styleName="anno"     />
                </mx:backgroundElements>
            </mx:LineChart>
```

But how do I accomplish this using as3? I understand it would look something like this    `chart.backgroundElement = AnArray`, however, in my case `chart.backgroundElements = com.mysite.RangeSelector` is not working. Please help!

Comment: I figured it out like so: var newObject:RangeSelector = new RangeSelector();
    
    var newArray:Array = new Array();
    newArray.push(newObject);
    
    
    linechart.backgroundElements = newArray;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out like so:

```
var newObject:RangeSelector = new RangeSelector(); 
var newArray:Array = new Array(); 
newArray.push(newObject); 
linechart.backgroundElements = newArray;
```